# What is the default Duration of asp.net MVC OutputCache attribute?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, caching, duration, outputcache

We are using MVC outputcache attribute, as shown below

```
[OutputCache(Location = System.Web.UI.OutputCacheLocation.Server, Duration = 60 * 60 * 12, VaryByParam = "staticDataTypes;customerSubscriptionId")]
```

Here what is the default value of  **Duration**?

Comment: The default value of duration is "0"

Comment: So if Duration value is 0, its like we are not caching?

Comment: yes, that it is. 0 means no caching.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Duration property is initialized in `System.Web.Configuration.OutputCacheProfile.cs`, here's the relevant code:

```
_propDuration = new ConfigurationProperty("duration", typeof(int), -1, 
                                          ConfigurationPropertyOptions.None);
```

and

```
[ConfigurationProperty("duration", DefaultValue = -1)]
public int Duration {
    get { 
         return (int)base[_propDuration];
    } 
    set { 
        base[_propDuration] = value;
    } 
}
```

Which sets it to a default of -1 which is an invalid value. Documentation for the  Duration property mentions: 'The Duration must be defined in either the profile or the directive of a page using the profile.'

So, there's actually no (valid) default value, you are required to specify it.